# Git pull after commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I have done a commit and then I remembered that there was a change on the branch, so I did a git pull. But this made a merge, so now it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to solve this? How to move my commit after the `origin/dev`? Please be explicit in steps, because I am a beginner.

Comment: Not sure i completely understand what you want to do, but it sounds like you should have rebased - git pull -r

Comment: yes, something like that... I have done a local commit and then I have done pull. I should have done pull then the changes... How to rebase?

Comment: Try: `git reset origin/dev` and then: `git checkout .`

Comment: And where are my commits? :D

Comment: Oh before you do that make sure you experiment stuff in another branch then the affected one.

Comment: Niiiceee... Luckily I have not done a big change...

Comment: @sop: Sorry that I was late in altering you. Always follow a pattern if you get stuck in such situations: 1: create another branch for experiment: `git checkout -b my-experiment-branch-name` 2: Make sure you have all changes committed in both the branch(previous and new one) then do experiments.

Comment: @sop Your changes are not lost, you just don't have a reference pointing at them. You could easily regain your changes by creating a branch pointing at your old *dev* position in the following fashion `git checkout -b backup 45eaea0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

```
git pull -r
```

Also, read this post about deleting merge commits by rebasing them:

http://marketblog.envato.com/general/rebasing-merge-commits-in-git/

Comment: :( I have done `git reset origin/dev` and then: `git checkout .`

Comment: then do git merge 45eaea0 and start again

Comment: If you want to avoid this from happening you can add this line to your config: `[merge] ff = only`